# How do I accomplish HTTP Tunneling by making use of IIS Web Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, tunneling

How do I accomplish HTTP Tunneling in C#/ASP.Net by making use of IIS Web Server as the mediator?
The client application can either be in C#(standalone), C++(activex), or even Flash and Javascript from a browser.

1. Is it correct to approach HTTP Tunneling as described above?
2. If so do I need to poll (long polling/short polling) the web server continuously from the client?

Answer (score 1):

ARR (Aplication Request Route) doesn't solve you question?